# servicestack.net ormlite with sqlite - prevent automatic primary key on create table

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, create-table, ormlite-servicestack

How do you stop ServiceStack.Net OrmLite from automatically making a primary key column?

My model is as follows:

```
public class Flower2Bee
{
    public int FlowerId { get; set; }
    public int BeeId { get; set; }
}
```

When I run db.CreateTable(true, typeof(Flower2Bee)), it gives FlowerId col a primary key index with a unique constraint.

Since the above model is intended for facilitating many-to-many relationships, this presents an obvious problem. I have also noticed this happening to other tables which are not intended to have primary keys.

My preference would be to turn this behaviour off, because I am happy to explicitly define primary keys with attributes where needed.

I am using OrmLite with SqLite, in case that is important.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known limitation of ServiceStack.Net OrmLite:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md#limitations

All tables must have a primary key in order to maintain compatibility with certain peristance technologies. The solution for the above question is to add a third Id property to the model to serve as the primary Id of each relationship row.